# How to create cookie with external domain?

Tags: javascript, cookies, cross-domain

I have created a `javascript` script which people can asynchronously load to their websites by pasting a small code like Facebook, Google does when we want to integrate their `javascript` SDK. From my script I want to create a cookie with my domain as Facebook , Google does with their domain. I'm trying to create cookie with domain by that [little framework given by Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie).

```
docCookies.setItem('cookie1', 'some value',Infinity, '/', '.example.com');
```

Where '.example.com' is my domain name where I have that script which people loading to their website. I'm trying to create that cookie in any domain which load my script. But it's not working, no cookies have been set so far. How I can create a cookie with my domain from that script to other domain?

[Sorry for my bad English.]

Answer (score 3):

This *might* be the explanation:

If I understand you correctly, your script is loaded from www.example.com, but used by sites on other domains, let's say www.someotherdomain.com.

If you create a cookie and try to use this cookie in a request *from* www.someotherdomain.com *to* www.example.com, the browser will consider this a third-party cookie. The cookie is a third-party cookie becuase the domain you're *at* (www.someotherdomain.com) differs from the domain the request is sent *to* (www.example.com).

Several browsers block third-party cookies, and the cookie is therefore not included in the request to www.example.com.

There's no way you can stop the browsers blocking third-party cookies, you'll have to look at alternative techniques.

Comment: Thanks for your information, Now I understand the fact. But what could be alternative techniques? I see facebook, google can put their third party cookies, so there should be some mechanism to set those cookies.

Comment: Depends a bit on what you're trying to do.

I had a similar problem, and my solution was to not use cookies (see here https://404it.no/en/blog/javascript_cross-domain_request_with_session)

If you are tracking the same cookie accross several domains, the above solutions won't work.

Comment: In my case, I can not use sessionStorage/localStorage etc.